# Sqlite rename empty table

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

Im trying to run the following line:

```
"ALTER TABLE flocksStartWeight RENAME TO flocksStartWeight_old"
```

Where flocksStartWeight is an empty sqlite(3.15.2) table.
When I run this in sqlite db browser it renames fine but when I try to run it from my qt application it fails with the warning.:

> "WARNING: DatabaseConnectionImplementation::executeQuery: Failed for
>   query "ALTER TABLE flocksStartWeight RENAME TO flocksStartWeight_old",
>   () WARNING: "No query Unable to fetch row"

relevant code:

executeQuery call

```
bool query2Successful = db->executeQuery("ALTER TABLE flocksStartWeight RENAME TO flocksStartWeight_old")->isValid();
```

The method

```
DatabaseResultUPtr DatabaseConnectionImplementation::executeQuery(const QString& query, const QVariantList& args)
{
    QMutexLocker tsLocker(&tsLock);

    if (!db.isOpen())
    {
        hDebug(TRACING_CONTEXT_RUNTIME_WARNING) << "DatabaseConnectionImplementation::executeQuery: Failed, database " << dbName << " not open";
        return DatabaseResultUPtr(new DatabaseResult());
    }

    QSqlQuery q(db);
    q.prepare(query);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < args.size() ; i++)
        q.bindValue(i, args.value(i));
    if (!q.exec())
    {
        hDebug(TRACING_CONTEXT_RUNTIME_WARNING) << "DatabaseConnectionImplementation::executeQuery: Failed for query " << q.executedQuery() << ", " << args;
        hDebug(TRACING_CONTEXT_RUNTIME_WARNING) << q.lastError().text();
        return DatabaseResultUPtr(new DatabaseResult());
    }

    QMutexLocker scoped_lock(&queryMutex);
    ++queryCount;

    return DatabaseResultUPtr(new DatabaseResult(q, this));
}
```

I do many similar renames and they all worked fine.
The only difference was that flocksStartWeight did not contain any data. So I manually added one row into the table and tried again. This time it worked fine.
How should I rename an empty table?
EDIT:

I added:

```
if(!q.prepare(query))
{
    qDebug() << "Preparing query failed for " << query;
}
```

It hits the qDebug line for the query, so It is already failing at the prepare method.

**EDIT:
When I asked the question I was assuming a database state that was wrong. the problem can not be reproduced, question can be removed.**

Comment: Maybe your SQLite browser's SQLite version differs from what your Qt plugin uses?

Comment: What is your Qt version?

Comment: When `QSqlQuery::exec()` is called, last error for the query is reset .. and now that you added a check for `prepare()` .. its here where you should show the last error .. (i.e before exec()) . Chances are the error you see now does not convey much about the problem.

Comment: _"question can be removed"_ Why don't you remove it by yourself (if it really needs to be removed of course) ? It would be simpler and quicker than waiting for a moderator to see your edit :)

Comment: @Fareanor You can not remove a question with a bounty on it by yourself.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart Oh I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling q.exec() last error for the query is reset.  You should show the last error before exec(). Since you added a check for prepare() it's there where you should show it.